# Update doesn't work in Terminal

Tags: 14.04, updates

When I write `sudo apt-get update` in Terminal ( Ubuntu 14.04 ), the end of results are these :

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_US
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty`/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: type in terminal gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list and remove the error line then update again

Comment: Why do you have entries for 12.04 in your sources?

Answer (score 1):

The update did not fail. It just could not retrieve one oft the PPAs you added. This PPA has been ignored and you are good to go.

Comment: so what shall I do, I think because of that when Ubuntu shows desktop it displays error to report... :(

Comment: No, this is not the cause of your problem. If you want to eliminate the error, you will have to edit your sources list.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :

```
1. Go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
2. Delete marlin-devs-marlin-daily-trusty.list.save file
```

Thank you all :)